# TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

Tags: firebase

Tenho seguinte trecho de código para upload storage firebse estou utilizando typescript.

```
uploadPhoto(photo) {
//Get File
this.file = photo.files[0]; // Erro nessa linha

this.metadata = {
  'contentType': this.file.type
};

//Create a storage ref
this.storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('images/');

// Upload file
this.storageRef.put(this.file, this.metadata);

}
```

ele dar seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse tipo de erro `TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined` geralmente ocorre por que o valor está perdido, seja por não passar o parâmetro ou por que ele não foi obtido ou setado. Se você percorrer o código desde o inicio, vai perceber que em algum momento esse valor foi perdido.

Comment: estou passando: uploadImage() {
    this.userProvider.uploadPhoto(this.photoField);
  }

Comment: Verifique o `this.photoField`. Ele deve estar como undefined.